# Xpath Expression for looping records from different files based on id

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have two source files

```
<corporations>
  <corporation>
    <CorporationID>1044293</CorporationID>
    <CorporationName>CorporationName1</CorporationName>
    <CorporationNumber>CorporationNumber1</CorporationNumber>
    <NVBusinessID>NVBusinessID1</NVBusinessID>
    <BusinessLicenseExp>2011-04-05T12:12:12</BusinessLicenseExp>
  </corporation>
  <corporation>
    <CorporationID>1044294</CorporationID>
    <CorporationName>CorporationName2</CorporationName>
    <CorporationNumber>CorporationNumber2</CorporationNumber>
    <NVBusinessID>NVBusinessID2</NVBusinessID>
    <BusinessLicenseExp>2011-04-05T12:12:12</BusinessLicenseExp>
  </corporation>
  <corporation>
    <CorporationID>1044295</CorporationID>
    <CorporationName>CorporationName3</CorporationName>
    <CorporationNumber>CorporationNumber3</CorporationNumber>
    <NVBusinessID>NVBusinessID3</NVBusinessID>
    <BusinessLicenseExp>2011-04-05T12:12:12</BusinessLicenseExp>
  </corporation>
</corporations>
```

and

```
<corporationActions>
  <corporationAction>
    <ActionID>5530960</ActionID>
    <CorporationID>1044293</CorporationID>
    <ActionDate>2008-05-03</ActionDate>
    <ActionType>ActionType1</ActionType>
    <ActionNotes></ActionNotes>
    <DocumentNumber>3</DocumentNumber>
    <NumberofPages>1</NumberofPages>
  </corporationAction>
  <corporationAction>
    <ActionID>5530974</ActionID>
    <CorporationID>1044294</CorporationID>
    <ActionDate>2009-05-03</ActionDate>
    <ActionType>ActionType2</ActionType>
    <ActionNotes></ActionNotes>
    <DocumentNumber>2</DocumentNumber>
    <NumberofPages>4</NumberofPages>
  </corporationAction>
  <corporationAction>
    <ActionID>5530975</ActionID>
    <CorporationID>1044294</CorporationID>
    <ActionDate>2009-05-03</ActionDate>
    <ActionType>ActionType3</ActionType>
    <ActionNotes></ActionNotes>
    <DocumentNumber>2</DocumentNumber>
    <NumberofPages>2</NumberofPages>
  </corporationAction>
  <corporationAction>
    <ActionID>5530976</ActionID>
    <CorporationID>1044295</CorporationID>
    <ActionDate>2011-05-03</ActionDate>
    <ActionType>ActionType4</ActionType>
    <ActionNotes></ActionNotes>
    <DocumentNumber>20110258778-91</DocumentNumber>
    <NumberofPages>4</NumberofPages>
  </corporationAction>
</corporationActions>
```

I need to get all those records (as Response) matching CorporationID from 1st File and find the corresponding CorporationID records (they can be multiple) from 2nd file and print in the following format

```
<sendCorporationActionDetailsVariable>
 <corporationActions>
  <ns1:corporationAction>
   <ns1:NVBusinessID>NVBusinessID1</ns1:NVBusinessID>
   <ns1:CorporationName>CorporationName1</ns1:CorporationName>
   <ns1:corporationActionDetails>
    <ns1:CorporationID>1044293</ns1:CorporationID>
    <ns1:ActionDate>04/05/2008</ns1:ActionDate>
    <ns1:ActionType>Articles of Organization1</ns1:ActionType>
   </ns1:corporationActionDetails>
  </ns1:corporationAction>

  <ns1:corporationAction>
   <ns1:NVBusinessID>NVBusinessID2</ns1:NVBusinessID>
   <ns1:CorporationName>NVBusinessID2</ns1:CorporationName>
   <ns1:corporationActionDetails>
    <ns1:CorporationID>1044294</ns1:CorporationID>
    <ns1:ActionDate>04/05/2011</ns1:ActionDate>
    <ns1:ActionType>ActionType2</ns1:ActionType>
   </ns1:corporationActionDetails>
  </ns1:corporationAction>

  <ns1:corporationAction>
   <ns1:NVBusinessID>NVBusinessID2</ns1:NVBusinessID>
   <ns1:CorporationName>NVBusinessID2</ns1:CorporationName>
  <ns1:corporationActionDetails>
    <ns1:CorporationID>1044294</ns1:CorporationID>
    <ns1:ActionDate>04/05/2010</ns1:ActionDate>
    <ns1:ActionType>ActionType3</ns1:ActionType>
   </ns1:corporationActionDetails>
  </ns1:corporationAction>

  <ns1:corporationAction>
   <ns1:NVBusinessID>NVBusinessID3</ns1:NVBusinessID>
   <ns1:CorporationName>CorporationName3</ns1:CorporationName>
   <ns1:corporationActionDetails>
    <ns1:CorporationID>1044295</ns1:CorporationID>
    <ns1:ActionDate>04/05/2011</ns1:ActionDate>
    <ns1:ActionType>ActionType4</ns1:ActionType>
   </ns1:corporationActionDetails>
  </ns1:corporationAction>
 </corporationActions>
</sendCorporationActionDetailsVariable>
```

Here is a portion of the response file:

```
<ns1:corporationAction>
 <ns1:NVBusinessID>NVBusinessID2</ns1:NVBusinessID>
 <ns1:CorporationName>NVBusinessID2</ns1:CorporationName>
 <ns1:corporationActionDetails>
  <ns1:CorporationID>1044294</ns1:CorporationID>
  <ns1:ActionDate>04/05/2011</ns1:ActionDate>
  <ns1:ActionType>ActionType2</ns1:ActionType>
 </ns1:corporationActionDetails>
</ns1:corporationAction>

<ns1:corporationAction>
 <ns1:NVBusinessID>NVBusinessID2</ns1:NVBusinessID>
 <ns1:CorporationName>NVBusinessID2</ns1:CorporationName>
<ns1:corporationActionDetails>
  <ns1:CorporationID>1044294</ns1:CorporationID>
  <ns1:ActionDate>04/05/2010</ns1:ActionDate>
  <ns1:ActionType>ActionType3</ns1:ActionType>
 </ns1:corporationActionDetails>
</ns1:corporationAction>
```

I need the above to be in the following format

```
<ns1:corporationAction>
   <ns1:NVBusinessID>NVBusinessID2</ns1:NVBusinessID>
   <ns1:CorporationName>NVBusinessID2</ns1:CorporationName>

   <ns1:corporationActionDetails>
    <ns1:CorporationID>1044294</ns1:CorporationID>
    <ns1:ActionDate>04/05/2011</ns1:ActionDate>
    <ns1:ActionType>ActionType2</ns1:ActionType>
   </ns1:corporationActionDetails>

  <ns1:corporationActionDetails>
    <ns1:CorporationID>1044294</ns1:CorporationID>
    <ns1:ActionDate>04/05/2010</ns1:ActionDate>
    <ns1:ActionType>ActionType3</ns1:ActionType>
   </ns1:corporationActionDetails>
</ns1:corporationAction>
```

I have written a logic which loop through for-each of the 1st file and 2nd file and compares corporationID and prints the required information.

```
<ns1:corporationActions>
  <xsl:for-each select="$InvokeCorpActFileReaderOutputVariable.body/ns0:corporationActions/ns0:corporationAction">
  <xsl:variable name="corpActPos" select="position()"/>
<xsl:for-each select="/tns:corporations/tns:corporation">
<xsl:variable name="corpPos" select="position()"/>

  <xsl:if test="$InvokeCorpActFileReaderOutputVariable.body/ns0:corporationActions/ns0:corporationAction[$corpActPos]/ns0:CorporationID = /tns:corporations/tns:corporation[$corpPos]/tns:CorporationID">
  <xsl:variable name="cntCorpId" select="count($InvokeCorpActFileReaderOutputVariable.body/ns0:corporationActions/ns0:corporationAction/ns0:CorporationID)"/>
    <ns1:corporationAction>
      <ns1:NVBusinessID>
        <xsl:value-of select="/tns:corporations/tns:corporation[$corpPos]/tns:NVBusinessID"/>
      </ns1:NVBusinessID>

<xsl:for-each select="$InvokeCorpActFileReaderOutputVariable.body/ns0:corporationActions/ns0:corporationAction[$corpActPos]/ns0:CorporationID">

  <ns1:corporationActionDetails>
        <ns1:CorporationID>
          <xsl:value-of select="$InvokeCorpActFileReaderOutputVariable.body/ns0:corporationActions/ns0:corporationAction[$corpActPos]/ns0:CorporationID"/>
        </ns1:CorporationID>
        <ns1:ActionDate>
          <xsl:value-of select="$InvokeCorpActFileReaderOutputVariable.body/ns0:corporationActions/ns0:corporationAction[$corpActPos]/ns0:ActionDate"/>
        </ns1:ActionDate>
        <ns1:ActionType>
          <xsl:value-of select="$InvokeCorpActFileReaderOutputVariable.body/ns0:corporationActions/ns0:corporationAction[$corpActPos]/ns0:ActionType"/>
        </ns1:ActionType>
  </ns1:corporationActionDetails>

</xsl:for-each>
    </ns1:corporationAction>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
</ns1:corporationActions>
```

Instead of this I need one XPATH expression which takes care of these.

Answer (score 0):

The wanted output cannot be produced only as the result of evaluating a single XPath expression. XPath is a query language for XML documents and as such, evaluating an XPath expression never changes the structure of any XML document and never modifies any node in any XML document.

You want nodes changed (such as the new nodes being in a new namespace -- to which the prefix `ns1:` is bound) -- this cannot be done just evaluating an XPath expression.

To perform such transformations, you need not only XPath but also another language that is hosting an XPath engine -- such as XSLT, XQuery or any programming language with DOM API.

Such a transformation can be written in a very compact way using XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ns1="my:ns1" exclude-result-prefixes="ns1" >
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="ActionByCorpId" match="corporationAction"
  use="CorporationID"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDoc2" select="document('delete16.xml')"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">

  <sendCorporationActionDetailsVariable>
   <corporationActions>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*/CorporationID"/>
   </corporationActions>
  </sendCorporationActionDetailsVariable>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="CorporationID">
   <xsl:variable name="vId" select="."/>

   <xsl:for-each select="$vDoc2/*">
     <xsl:apply-templates mode="addNamespace"
      select="key('ActionByCorpId',$vId)"/>
   </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="addNamespace">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="addNamespace"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*" mode="addNamespace">
  <xsl:element name="ns1:{name()}" namespace="my:ns1">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="addNamespace"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<corporations>
    <corporation>
        <CorporationID>1044293</CorporationID>
        <CorporationName>CorporationName1</CorporationName>
        <CorporationNumber>CorporationNumber1</CorporationNumber>
        <NVBusinessID>NVBusinessID1</NVBusinessID>
        <BusinessLicenseExp>2011-04-05T12:12:12</BusinessLicenseExp>
    </corporation>
    <corporation>
        <CorporationID>1044294</CorporationID>
        <CorporationName>CorporationName2</CorporationName>
        <CorporationNumber>CorporationNumber2</CorporationNumber>
        <NVBusinessID>NVBusinessID2</NVBusinessID>
        <BusinessLicenseExp>2011-04-05T12:12:12</BusinessLicenseExp>
    </corporation>
    <corporation>
        <CorporationID>1044295</CorporationID>
        <CorporationName>CorporationName3</CorporationName>
        <CorporationNumber>CorporationNumber3</CorporationNumber>
        <NVBusinessID>NVBusinessID3</NVBusinessID>
        <BusinessLicenseExp>2011-04-05T12:12:12</BusinessLicenseExp>
    </corporation>
</corporations>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<sendCorporationActionDetailsVariable>
   <corporationActions>
      <ns1:corporationAction xmlns:ns1="my:ns1">
         <ns1:ActionID>5530960</ns1:ActionID>
         <ns1:CorporationID>1044293</ns1:CorporationID>
         <ns1:ActionDate>2008-05-03</ns1:ActionDate>
         <ns1:ActionType>ActionType1</ns1:ActionType>
         <ns1:ActionNotes/>
         <ns1:DocumentNumber>3</ns1:DocumentNumber>
         <ns1:NumberofPages>1</ns1:NumberofPages>
      </ns1:corporationAction>
      <ns1:corporationAction xmlns:ns1="my:ns1">
         <ns1:ActionID>5530974</ns1:ActionID>
         <ns1:CorporationID>1044294</ns1:CorporationID>
         <ns1:ActionDate>2009-05-03</ns1:ActionDate>
         <ns1:ActionType>ActionType2</ns1:ActionType>
         <ns1:ActionNotes/>
         <ns1:DocumentNumber>2</ns1:DocumentNumber>
         <ns1:NumberofPages>4</ns1:NumberofPages>
      </ns1:corporationAction>
      <ns1:corporationAction xmlns:ns1="my:ns1">
         <ns1:ActionID>5530975</ns1:ActionID>
         <ns1:CorporationID>1044294</ns1:CorporationID>
         <ns1:ActionDate>2009-05-03</ns1:ActionDate>
         <ns1:ActionType>ActionType3</ns1:ActionType>
         <ns1:ActionNotes/>
         <ns1:DocumentNumber>2</ns1:DocumentNumber>
         <ns1:NumberofPages>2</ns1:NumberofPages>
      </ns1:corporationAction>
      <ns1:corporationAction xmlns:ns1="my:ns1">
         <ns1:ActionID>5530976</ns1:ActionID>
         <ns1:CorporationID>1044295</ns1:CorporationID>
         <ns1:ActionDate>2011-05-03</ns1:ActionDate>
         <ns1:ActionType>ActionType4</ns1:ActionType>
         <ns1:ActionNotes/>
         <ns1:DocumentNumber>20110258778-91</ns1:DocumentNumber>
         <ns1:NumberofPages>4</ns1:NumberofPages>
      </ns1:corporationAction>
   </corporationActions>
</sendCorporationActionDetailsVariable>
```

Comment: when i have tested the above code in xmlspy i got an empty response (created delted16.xml and placed in the same folder...

Comment: The delete16.xml file must be in the same folder as the xslt file. Otherwise absolute URL must be provided in the `document()` function.

Comment: I don't use XML-SPY and sometimes it happens to be buggy. Try specifying the absolute file URL. Or maybe the document() function is forbidden by default and there is some special, XML-SPY way of enabling it -- read the documentation.

Comment: @anvv sharma: Use `document('file:///c:/temp/delete16.xml')` this works with all XSLT processors. Some XSLT processors, such as XML-SPY resolve a relative URI off the folder in which their executable is -- not off the folder where the primary stylesheet file resides. I have to check, but most probably this is a bug in any such XSLT processor.